# N channel MOSFET controlled using teensy 3.6 gpio

Tags: mosfet, teensy

I'm trying to drive some LEDs from the 3.3v located on my teensy 3.6 device (a microcontroller) using an n channel MOSFET. I cannot drive this directly from the gpios ports due to the current being drawn from the LEDs. Now, the gate voltage is 3.3v (controlled via PWM) and the drain voltage is also 3.3v. The mosfet im using is IRF7807ZPBF but I'm having a few issues toggling the LEDs. I'll post a schematics when I'm back, but could someone give me some hints to think about please?

Thanks

Comment: When you get back take note of the numbers by the word "close".

Comment: @nasher128 ask specific questions and post all relevant information. A well written question with good information (so we know what your talking about) will get good answers, a poorly written question will generate discussion, confusion and be closed.

Comment: i buy IRLZ44Ns in bulk for cheap and effective 3.3v switching: VGSth=1.0-2.0v, but if anyone knows of something better, please share!

Answer (score 1):

Datasheet check on your FET:

RDS(on) Static Drain-to-Source On-Resistance

Max 18 mOhm @ Vgs = 4.5V

It is not specified for 3.3V Vgs drive. Please use a FET specified for 3.3V or less. This way, you can be sure it will turn on with the voltage you got.

Or you could use a bipolar, can't say without knowing the current. Or maybe your LEDs need 3.6V to light up, but you don't provide any info.